# Showing that $\left|\frac{1}{z^4+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{1-r^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, inequality

> I am trying to show that if $|z|=r<1$, then
>   $$\left|\frac{1}{z^4+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{1-r^4} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

I have shown the inequality $$\left|\frac{1}{z^3+1}\right|\leq\frac{1}{1-r^3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$ holds under the same conditions, but I am having showing the result of $(1)$.

I considered \begin{align}
|z^4+1|&\geq\left||z^4|-|-1|\right| \\
&=\left||z|^4-1\right| \\
&=\left|r^4-1\right|
\end{align}
Now, $r^4-1$ is positive $\forall r<1$\ $\{0\}$ $(r\neq -1)$. Ideally, like in $(2)$, if $r^4-1$ was strictly negative then the result would immediately follow.

A hint would be very helpful.

Comment: This is the same as saying, that if $|w|<1$, then $|1+w|\ge 1-|w|$.

Comment: By the reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: $|z^4+1|\geq 1- |z|^4=1-r^4>0.$

Comment: I'm still unclear. It looks like you're using the reverse triangle inequality, which I thought was defined as $\left|z_1-z_2\right|\geq\left||z_1|-|z_2|\right|$ for every complex number $z_1, z_2$. It looks as though you have assumed that $|z_1|-|z_2|$, or in this case, $1-r^4$ is positive. I don't think this is the case.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2870628/showing-that-left-fraczz31-right-leq-fracrr3-1/2870644#2870644

Comment: @Bell You state in the first line that $|z|=r<1$. Consequently, $(1-r^{4})^{-1}$ is positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that

$$\left|\frac{1}{z^4+1}\right|=\frac1{\left|z^4+1\right|}$$

and since

$$\left|z^4+1\right|\ge \left|r^4-1\right|=1-r^4\ge 0$$

the result follows.

Comment: How is $1-r^4\geq 0$ when $r$ is defined as $r<1$?

Comment: r is no negative  that is $0\le r<1$

Comment: This is the part I don't understand. I'm unsure of why $r$ cannot be negative? Now that you say it, I agree that the inequality $(1)$ doesn't hold if $r<0$. How did you see this immediately? I overlooked this completely and assumed that $r\in(-\infty,0)$ as $r<1$.

Comment: recall that $ r=|z|\ge 0$

Comment: I'm so stupid. I think I just tried to over complicate the question haha thanks a lot

Comment: Now it’s clear! Well done. Bye

Answer (score 0):

By the reverse triangle inequality it holds that $|z^4+1| = |1-(-z^4)| \geq 1-|z|^4$ and therefore $\frac{1}{|z^4+1|} \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|^4} = \frac{1}{1-r^4}$

Comment: Note that the reverse triangle inequality says that $|z-w| \geq | |z| - |w| |$ but this implies that $|z-w| \geq |z| - |w| $ because if $ |z| - |w| < 0$ then the equality holds trivially since $|z-w| \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As Lord Shark (indirectly) mentioned, the exponent does not play a role here, as $|z|^n = |z^n|$.

So, it is enough to show that $1-|w| \leq |1 + w|$ for $|w| < 1$, which is a direct consequence of $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b| \stackrel{b \rightarrow -b}{\Longrightarrow} ||a|-|b||\leq |a+b|$